# A sub-Riemannian geometry is completely determined by its Hamiltonian

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have met the following claim in Montgomery's book, A Tour of Subriemannian Goemetries (pag. 25)

> A sub-Riemannian geometry is completely determined by its Hamiltonian

Now, I know a sub-Riemannian geometry is a triple $(M,Q,h)$ where $Q\hookrightarrow TM$ is a regular distribution (usually assumed bracket-generating to apply Chow's theorem) and $h$ is a metric on $Q$.
Now, as I have understood, this is equivalent to give a cometric, i.e. an innner product on $T^*M$ as follows:

> Denote by $\flat_h:Q\rightarrow Q^*$ the isomorphism defined fiberwise on a section X of Q as
> $$X_x\in Q_x\mapsto h(x)(X_x,\cdot)\in Q_x^*$$
> Denote its inverse by $\#_h:=\flat_h^{-1}: Q^*\rightarrow Q$
> Consider the adjoint map of the inclusion $i:Q\hookrightarrow TM$,, with respect to the canonical evaluation pairing,  i.e. the map $i^*:TM^*\hookrightarrow Q^*$ which is determined fiberwise on a section $\alpha$ of $T^*M$ by:
> $$\alpha_x\in T_x^*M\mapsto i^*(\alpha_x)\quad\text{where}\quad\langle i^*(\alpha_x), X_x\rangle=\langle \alpha_x, i(X_x)\rangle\quad\quad\forall X_x\in Q_x$$
> Then we can define a conjugate map $g:T^*M\rightarrow TM$ fiberwise on a section $\alpha$ of $T^*M$ as:
> $$\alpha_x\in T^*_xM\mapsto i(\#_h(i^*(\alpha_x)))$$
> this is a linear vector bundle map, fibred over the identity.
> From $g$ we can define the desired cometric, denoted by $\tilde{g}$, as:
> $$\tilde{g}(x)(\alpha_x,\beta_x)=\langle g(\alpha_x),\beta_x\rangle\quad\quad \forall x\in M\forall \alpha_x,\beta_x\in T_x^*M$$
> Observe it holds
> $$\tilde{g}(x)(\alpha_x,\beta_x)=h(x)(g(\alpha_x),g(\beta_x))\quad \star$$
> Starting from a cometric $\tilde{g}$ of constant rank, $k$, by the second last equality we can first define $g$ and a distribution $Q=Im(g)$ of rank $k$. Then $g$ produces the desired metric $h$ through $\star$
> Clearly the two constructions are inverses.

Now, any sub-Riemannian metric produces, through its associated cometric $(\cdot,\cdot)_q$
$$H:M\times T^*M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\quad\quad (q,p)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}(p,p)_q$$
which is called a sub-Riemannian Hamiltonian.

What is not clear to me is how given an arbitrary function $H:M\times T^*M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we can retrieve a cometric which induces it (if we succeed, then we can apply arguments above to finish). Indeed, if $H$ it is non negative, we can try put
$$\forall \alpha_x\in T^*_xM\quad \tilde{g}(x)(\alpha_X,\alpha_x)=2H(x,\alpha_x)$$

But shouldn't we impose addditional conditions to assure polarization idenitity hold to retrieve a product from this tentative quadratic form ?

EDIT: here is the passage from Montgomery's. With respect to the notation above $M=Q$ and $g=\beta$
[image]

Comment: The Hamiltonian is not a function $M\times T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$, it is just a function $T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$. Also, it's not true that every function $H:T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$ can be associated with a sub-Riemannian structure, but it is true that if an associated sub-Riemannian structure exists, it is unique.

Comment: @Kajelad  Well, I took the definition of Hamiltonian from Montgomery's book, but I guess they are essentially equivalent. I edit the question with a photo of the book, because what you say is precisely what I thinked in the beginning, but it seems at odds with what the author claims

Comment: They are not at all equivalent. Also, Montgomery adds the requirements that $H$ be nonnegative, fiberwise quadratic, and constant rank. All of these are needed for a sub-Riemannian structure to exist.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes, and my question is now precisely how to exploit this conditions to retrieve this sub-Riemannian structure

Comment: Moreover can you elaborate on the definition of Hamiltonian, as you see I took that of Montgomery. Why does he defines as a map taking as input both a point and a covector while you say it is not an equivalent approach to the usual one? I don't have any background on mathematical physics at all, so I don't know about conventions you may deem obvious. I just read the book

Comment: Each element of $T^*M$ belongs to a particular cotangent space, and so already has a point associated to it. The (abuse of) notation $H(q,p)$ is due to the fact that $T^*M$ may be described by local coordinates $(q^1,\cdots,q^n,p_1,\cdots,p_n)$, but one should think of $(p,q)$ together as an element of $T^*M$.